# jQuery scrollLeft is not scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a container `div` with a `ul` inside of it setup like this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BQPVL/1/

Why isn't the scroll working?

HTML:

```
<div id="outside">
  <ul id="inside">
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>how are you?</li>
    <li>i am good.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="left">&larr;</button>
<button id="right">&rarr;</button>
```

CSS:

```
#outside {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
#inside {
  width: 1000px;
}
#inside li {
  background: red;
  width: 99px;
  height: 40px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var position = $("#inside").scrollLeft();
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#right").bind("click", function() {
    $("#inside").animate({
      scrollLeft: position + 100
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the edit but I witnessed too many times broken (removed, erased...) fiddle links here on SO. (I added your relevant code)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to `scrollLeft` the element that has the `overflow` property, and that's your `#outside`

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/eyiney/1/edit)***

```
$(function() {  // DOM READY shorthand

  $("#right, #left").click(function() {
    var dir = this.id=="right" ? '+=' : '-=' ;
    $("#outside").stop().animate({scrollLeft: dir+'100'}, 1000);
  });

});
```

as you can see you can attach both your buttons to the click handler, and inside it retrieve the clicked button `id`.
If `this.id` returns `"right"` var `dir` wil become `"+="`, otherwise logically
you clicked the `#left` one and `dir` will hold `"-="`

Answer (score 1):

#### Works perfectly

You need to give `offset()` or `position()`. And animate the `left` property.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#right").bind("click", function() {
    var position = $("#inside").position();
    $("#inside").animate({
      left: position.left - 100
    }, 1000);
  });
});
$("#left").bind("click", function() {
  var position = $("#inside").position();
  $("#inside").animate({
    left: position.left + 100
  }, 1000);
});
```

#### Corrections

1. And when you give a `float: left;` you need to clear your floats. Please wait till the fiddle is ready...
2. You haven't loaded the jQuery in your fiddle.
3. Need to give `position: relative;` to the `UL`.

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BQPVL/9/

Comment: I'd also put everything inside of the `$(document).ready()` callback.

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle, and it still isn't working. I'm using 6.0.2 Safari.

Comment: @afterimagedesign Many issues... You haven't loaded jQuery.

Comment: @afterimagedesign Check http://jsfiddle.net/BQPVL/6/ and see the **Corrections** part.

Comment: @Blender It is already in the doc ready right? Except the position?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: The second `$('#right')` event handler (which should be fixed to say `left`) won't fire if `$('#left')` isn't ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this: http://jsfiddle.net/BQPVL/10/

```
$("#right").on("click", function () {
  $("#inside").stop(true, true).animate({
    left: '-=100'
  }, 1000);
});
$("#left").on("click", function () {
  $("#inside").stop(true, true).animate({
    left:'+=100'
  }, 1000);
});
```